# Zombie process are not being cleaned

Tags: linux

On my RHEL 6.7 VM number of zombie process are increasing by time. The zombies are not consuming any memory or cpu but I see them using top command.
I used #kill -9 PID and #kill -SIGCHLD PID but nothing happens.

I was trying to #kill -9 4650 and #kill -SIGCHLD 4650. ( 4650 is PPID) Also tried to kill the child. while killing child it shows no error. while killing parent it shows "Operation not permited"

Comment: Sounds like whatever it is stuck on is in an Uninterruptable System Call. I would run `strace` and try to figure out what is sitting on.

Comment: Or your not root and the process is owned by root.

Answer (score 1):

The parent process is not "mopping" them up. The parent process should be calling [wait](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) system call.

A quick solution is to kill the parent process. Then they become orphaned and will disappear from `top` as `init` will sort the problem out.

Comment: While trying to kill the parent process as root, it says "Operation not permitted"

Comment: You are trying to kill the process that is the parent of the zombie process (not `init`)

Comment: root     17597  4650  0 Apr11 ?        00:00:00 [seosd] <defunct>
root     17710  4650  0 Apr11 ?        00:00:00 [seosd] <defunct>
root     17768  4650  0 Apr11 ?        00:00:00 [report_agent.sh] <defunct>   I was trying to #kill -9 4650 and #kill -SIGCHLD 4640. Also tried to kill the child. while killing child it shows no error. while killing parent it shows "Operation not permited".

Comment: Please add this to the question (you can edit it) along with the heading from the command

Comment: PS: Are you logging into the machine with the appropriate username (or root)?

Answer (score 0):

They do not consume memory or cpu because zombie process is just an process state record without actual process associated to it. It is left behind so that parent process can find out the exit code of the child process. Unless you are author of the program of the parent process and intend to fix it, there is not much gain to be had trying to make them disappear.